# why there isn't a way to post pictures in the comments

Tags: feature-request

it is a MUST feature! you can really give a proper answer to a comment cause the only method you have is some characters... even a new line is prohibited.

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't *be* providing an answer in the form of a comment... That's what *answers* are for! Can you point out an example of a situation where such a feature would be helpful?

Comment: i don't have an example (i forgot when i needed it :) ) but generally when i what to give an example for what to investigate when extra information is needed to give an answer on the question.

Comment: I would just link to the picture like this: http://lorempixum.com/400/200/ and then leave it to the user to click to expand the picture in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

its more annoying when I want to include a pic with my question and can't cause i'm new. first forum that i've ever visited to do this.

Comment: This is not a regular forum. The idea and application of privileges is important. Check the FAQ.

Comment: The idea of a forum is to be able to give as much info at once and receive as much back. Pics are a great help! The FAQ on this site mentions nothing about this. Besides this is the definition of a forum. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forum

Comment: Sorry, but this is decidedly not a forum, it is a question and answer site. Following a question and answer format (and enforcing a few simple rules) encourages people to post higher quality material than a forum environment is capable of producing. If you need to post pictures, post an answer. Just make sure that it answers the question asked.

Comment: you seem a bit confused. [New users are prohibited from embedding images](http://diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user), but this restriction is removed once you've accumulated 10 reputation points (one up-vote on an answer, two on a question). If you absolutely *need* to post an image before then, just convince a user with more reputation to edit it in for you.